# Why is the ViewEngineCollection for WebForms loaded in a asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is a asp.net mvc project using Razor ViewEngine (.cshtml files)

Why is the WebFormViewEngine then loaded into memory?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft bloggers routinely state that MVC is still using a lot of ASP.NET system code.

Comment: You have to differentiate. There is the framework ASP.NET. It offer multiple view engines. I did not ask why there is asp.net loaded. I asked for the ViewEngine. Razor does not depend in any to WebForms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 3 uses Razor and WebForms view engines by default. For instance imagine you ported old MVC 1 project with WebForms views to MVC 3. If you dont use WebForms then you can safely remove it in Global.asax:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    public void Application_Start()
    {
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create applications that are hybrids that use ASPX engine for some pages and Razor for others.

That is why this is loaded..

You're free to remove it in `global.asax`.